# can Sharing rules provides access to forecast hierarchy

Tags: sharing, sharing-rule, role-hierarchy, forecast, forecasts-collaborative

```
Role A
  Role A1
  Role A2
  Role A3
Role B
  Role B1
  Role B2
Role C
  Role C1
```

I have sharing rule on Opportunity to share the records of A1,A2,A3,B1,B2 to C1.
But in the forecast tab, For C1 , he is viewing only his Opportunities. Will sharing rule doesn't work in Forecast hierarchy. ?

Opportunity OWD: Private.

Answer (score 0):

Forecasting has its own sharing model unrelated to Opportunities. Each person can only see their own forecast, plus the Forecast Managers above them in either the Role Hierarchy or Territory Hierarchy (if Territory Management is enabled). If a user wants to share their forecast, they can do so as outlined in the [Share Forecasts and Manage Shared Forecasts](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.forecasts3_share_forecasts.htm&type=5) help topic.